# So, one of these questions is a shopping question, but the other one isn't?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I see [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5806/should-i-buy-a-car-or-get-my-current-one-repaired) was asked yesterday and received plenty of upvotes and answers, and that's fine with me it's a relevant question. However, I asked [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5760/should-i-lease-buy-new-or-buy-used) and it was closed as open-ended an off topic, and one commenter noted it was a shopping question and a discussion question.

I don't see much difference other than the first question stated a specific car that was already owned, whereas my question asked for concrete answers based on several factors. Both could be subjective and opinion based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the biggest difference is that question [Should I buy a car or get my current one repaired?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/5806/85) Had a specific car and situation, including factoring in mechanical repairs.

Your question might be better suited on [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/) as it's more of a money question than a repair question.

Comment: +1 for the Personal Finance SE site, it is indeed more of a money question.

Comment: @MDMoore313 I am trying to get the question migrated to that site. I am waiting on the okay from a mod on that site.

Comment: @MDMoore313 [I have migrated the post.](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21616/should-i-lease-buy-new-or-buy-used) If you will associate your accounts when you log in you will be able to edit the question etc.

Comment: Thank you for the migration.

Comment: Good move - that didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 3):

Do you think the other question should be closed?  If so, there is a link to vote to "close" at the bottom.

I saw the same question that you cite.  It didn't have any close votes and it did cite some potential specific maintenance issues:

> The main problems found were:
>
> Replace rear brake pads
>
> Replace right upper control arm
>
> Replace valve cover gaskets
>
> Replace power steering pump
>
> Replace left side axle seal
>
> Wheel alignment

If you have a different opinion, please feel free to express it.  Likewise, if you'd like to rephrase your question as one more in line with the FAQ, we welcome that as well.

Comment: I don't think it should be closed, just trying to get an understanding of the differences that may have kept it open, vs. my own question, as they are fairly similar, and you did describe one in your answer.